# Replace part in some string written in separate file that is being used in other file javascript

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, template-strings

I have a config file that has different URLs for different environments. I am using the object key for base url from the given object.

```
const configDev = {
    API: {
        url: 'http://api.domain.com',
    },
};
```

I want to add one string based on the module and add it to the above URL string like this.

```
const configDev = {
    API: {
        url: 'http://contact.api.domain.com', // if module name is not passed then it would be same as above.
    },
};
```

This configDev object is being used in some other place in the project.

How can I place in the variable in the above-given JSON data and replace the value in the variable?

I am using configDev variable in another file like this:

```
const HTTP = axios.create({
    baseURL: CONFIG.API.url, // CONFIG value is different based on differnt environment.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you got *configDev* in some other place in project you can split *url* string and insert desired value

```
const splittedUrl = configDev.API.url.split('://');
```

> splittedUrl = [ 'http', 'api.domain.com' ]

```
const targetUrl = `${ spilttedUrl[0] }://contact.${ spilttedUrl[1] }`
```

Comment: This is not what I'm asking for, how to place the dynamic string into URL value as given in the example above.

Comment: You can make configDev as function and pass dynamic value in argument. The function will return an object with desired value.

Comment: I cannot make it function as this is a configuration file.

Comment: I changed my suggestion above